# Using AJAX in WordPress Widget

Tags: widgets, jquery, ajax

The past few days I've been Googling and searching for answers to no avail. I'm building out a "Featured Content" widget where the user can easily (via ajax/jquery) search for posts.

Is it possible to use AJAX/jQuery strictly in the Widget area, or would this type of application have to be plugin-based?

Comment: I don't follow why do you "or" these two things?.. Plugin is just a convention for code organization, it has no impact on what code does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX/jQuery is not limited to any specific "area" like plugins or widgets, in fact some plugins consist solely of widgets (although afaik the converse cannot be said). [This Smashing article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/) might be a good primer. When you finish with that then check out [Gary Cao's WordPress + AJAX tips](http://solislab.com/blog/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/) and come back with a more specific question.